# For each only returns first iteration

Tags: php, foreach

I'm trying to run through an object. I'm having  an issue with my initial for each only running through the first iteration. So everything is great, but I'm only getting one iteration while their are 3. Any ideas why this may be happening?

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
/*Begin*/
$itemsTable = $wpdb->prefix . "HFW_portfolio_items";
$catTable = $wpdb->prefix . "HFW_portfolio_categories";
$tagTable = $wpdb->prefix . "HFW_portfolio_tags";
$rowsItemA = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM"." $itemsTable"."", ARRAY_A);
exit(var_dump($rowsItemA));
$numItems = count($rowsItem);
$i = 0;


//exit(var_dump($rowsItem));
foreach ($rowsItemA as $rowsItem ){
    //$id = $rowsItem[id];


    $port_item = "";
    $id = stripslashes ($rowsItem[id]);
    //exit(var_dump($id));
    $portfolio_category = stripslashes ($rowsItem[portfolio_category]);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM"." $catTable"." WHERE id="."$portfolio_category"." LIMIT 1";
    $catNameDB = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
    /*from Above Select for CATEGORY*/
    foreach ($catNameDB as $catNameDBs ){
        $portfolio_category = stripslashes ($catNameDBs->cat_name);
    }/**/
    $portfolio_name = stripslashes ($rowsItem[portfolio_name]);
    $portfolio_active = stripslashes ($rowsItem[portfolio_active]);
    $portfolio_tags = stripslashes ($rowsItem[portfolio_tags]);
    $portfolio_main_image = stripslashes ($rowsItem[main_image]);
    $portfolio_desc = stripslashes ($rowsItem[portfolio_desc]);
    $image_2 = stripslashes ($rowsItem[image_2]);
    $image_3 = stripslashes ($rowsItem[image_3]);
    $portfolio_website = stripslashes ($rowsItem[portfolio_website]);
    //exit(var_dump($image_2,$image_3));
    if($image_2 !== '' || $image_2 = null)
        {
            $image_2 = ",'".$image_2."',";
        }
    else
        {
            $image_2 = '';
        }
    if($image_3 !== '' || $image_3 = null)
        {
            $image_3 = ",'".$image_3."'";
        }
    else
        {
            $image_3 = '';
        }
    $port_item .= "
    {
        'title'         : '".$portfolio_name."',
        'description'   : '".$portfolio_desc."',
        'thumbnail'     : ['".$portfolio_main_image."' ".$image_2." ".$image_3."],
        'large'         : ['".$portfolio_main_image."' ".$image_2." ".$image_3."],
        'tags'          : ['".$portfolio_category."']
    }
    ";
    if(++$i === $numItems) {
        $port_item .= "";
    }
    else 
        $port_item .=",";
        //exit(var_dump($i,$numItems));
}
?>
```

> exit(var_dump($rowsItemA));

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=10)
      'id' => string '9' (length=1)
      'portfolio_name' => string 'Da' (length=26)
      'main_image' => string 'elicate-dashley-1.png' (length=101)
      'image_2' => string 'n-and-mn.png' (length=107)
      'image_3' => string '' (length=0)
      'portfolio_active' => string '0' (length=1)
      'portfolio_category' => string '1' (length=1)
      'portfolio_desc' => string 'test1' (length=246)
      'portfolio_tags' => string '["1","2","3","4","5","6","10"]' (length=30)
      'portfolio_website' => string 'http://www.test.com/' (length=26)
  1 => 
    array (size=10)
      'id' => string '10' (length=2)
      'portfolio_name' => string 'Sage' (length=29)
      'main_image' => string 'purs-er.png' (length=99)
      'image_2' => string '' (length=0)
      'image_3' => string '' (length=0)
      'portfolio_active' => string '0' (length=1)
      'portfolio_category' => string '1' (length=1)
      'portfolio_desc' => string 'test 2' (length=249)
      'portfolio_tags' => string '["1","2","5","6","9","10"]' (length=26)
      'portfolio_website' => string 'http://www.test.com/test' (length=27)
  2 => 
    array (size=10)
      'id' => string '11' (length=2)
      'portfolio_name' => string 'Scap' (length=20)
      'main_image' => string 's-day-cap.png' (length=93)
      'image_2' => string '' (length=0)
      'image_3' => string '' (length=0)
      'portfolio_active' => string '0' (length=1)
      'portfolio_category' => string '1' (length=1)
      'portfolio_desc' => string 'test 3' (length=155)
      'portfolio_tags' => string '["1","2","5","6","9","10"]' (length=26)
      'portfolio_website' => string 'http://www.test.com/test/test' (length=44)
```

Comment: What is the output for `var_dump($rowsItemA)`?

Comment: Added in original post

Comment: How did you come to know that you are only getting one iteration?

Comment: When I echo $port_item below only 1 is outputted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because, you have made `$port_item = ""` in brginning of the loop.

```
foreach ($rowsItemA as $rowsItem ){


    $port_item = "";// declaring as null here(remove this.)
```

So in every loop your value is reinitialized, and you are getting only 1 element(last element of your array)